# Confused about GLSL shader, how it calculates index

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader, react-three-fiber

I am at the last part of the book of shader that I need to finish learning having already completed everything else. I am having trouble understanding how the shader calculates the index dependent on the function given. I understand how the function mod is used and what the representation of it on a graph looks like but how the shader places the index number according to the position of the mod function assigned is confusing me. I labeled the piece of the code where I am confused at below and put the link to the page in the book of shader to see the code in action.

https://thebookofshaders.com/09/

```
// Author @patriciogv ( patriciogonzalezvivo.com ) - 2015

#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

#define PI 3.14159265358979323846

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform float u_time;

vec2 rotate2D (vec2 _st, float _angle) {
    _st -= 0.5;
    _st =  mat2(cos(_angle),-sin(_angle),
                sin(_angle),cos(_angle)) * _st;
    _st += 0.5;
    return _st;
}

vec2 tile (vec2 _st, float _zoom) {
    _st *= _zoom;
    return fract(_st);
}

vec2 rotateTilePattern(vec2 _st){
    _st *= 2.0;


!!!(THIS SECTION BELOW ON GIVING THE INDEX NUMER)

    //  Give each cell an index number
    //  according to its position
    float index = 0.0;
    index += step(1., mod(_st.x,2.0));
    index += step(1., mod(_st.y,2.0))*(2.0);

    //      |
    //  2   |   3
    //      |
    //--------------
    //      |
    //  0   |   1
    //      |

!!!(THIS SECTION ABOVE ON GIVING THE INDEX NUMER)

    // Make each cell between 0.0 - 1.0
    _st = fract(_st);

    if(index == 1.0){
        _st = rotate2D(_st,PI*0.5);
    } else if(index == 2.0){
        _st = rotate2D(_st,PI*-0.5);
    } else if(index == 3.0){
        _st = rotate2D(_st,PI);
    }

    return _st;
}

void main (void) {
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;

    st = tile(st,3.0);
    st = rotateTilePattern(st);
   
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(step(st.x,st.y)),1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
vec2 rotateTilePattern(vec2 _st){
    // _st argument contains values between [0,3] after tile(st, 3.0)
    // call in main method
    _st *= 2.0; 
    // _st now contains values between [0, 6] 

    // going clockwise
    // x axis starts on the right, y axis starts from the bottom
    // The first quadrant with index 2 is for x = [0, 1] and y = [1, 2]
    // The second quadrant with index 3 is for x = [1, 2] and y = [1, 2]
    // The third quadrant with index 1 is for x = [1, 2] and y = [0, 1]
    // The fourth quadrant with index 0 is for x = [0, 1] and y = [0, 1]

    // So lets try with values x=.5 and y=.5 which lie in the fourth quadrant
    // index should equal 0
    // mod(.5, 2.0) is .5
    // step(1., .5) is 0
    // so index += 0 is still 0.0
    // mod(.5, 2.0) is .5
    // step(1., .5) is 0
    // 0 * 2 is 0
    // so index += 0 equals 0 as expected

    // Lets try with values x=1.5 and y=1.5 which lie in the second quadrant
    // index should equal 3
    // mod(1.5, 2.0) is 1.5
    // step(1., 1.5) is 1
    // so index += 1 is now equal to 1.0
    // mod(1.5, 2.0) is 1.5
    // step(1., 1.5) is 1
    // 1 * 2 is 2
    // so index += 2 equals 3 as expected

    // the mod will treat any value [2-4] or [4-6] the same as [0-2]


!!!(THIS SECTION BELOW ON GIVING THE INDEX NUMER)

    //  Give each cell an index number
    //  according to its position
    float index = 0.0;
    index += step(1., mod(_st.x,2.0));
    index += step(1., mod(_st.y,2.0))*(2.0);

    //      |
    //  2   |   3
    //      |
    //--------------
    //      |
    //  0   |   1
    //      |

!!!(THIS SECTION ABOVE ON GIVING THE INDEX NUMER)
```

Comment: fkn hell I get it now, thank you for the time spent on the comment